# UPDATE statement for MySQL with specified fields

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, sql-insert

I have a array that I am inserting into a database with an INSERT statement like below.

```
INSERT INTO import_io 
(`total`, `thru`, `name/_source`, `name`, `name/_text`, `strokes`) 
VALUES ('-6','F','/golf/pga/players/Marc+Leishman/8442/scorecard/2014/35','http://sports.yahoo.com/golf/pga/players/Marc+Leishman/8442/scorecard/2014/35','Marc Leishman','64')
```

Is there anyway to use the UPDATE statement instead of an INSERT with having to split up the values so that I can go something like...

```
UPDATE import_io 
SET (`total`, `thru`, `name/_source`, `name`, `name/_text`, `strokes`) 
VALUES ('-6','F','/golf/pga/players/Marc+Leishman/8442/scorecard/2014/35','http://sports.yahoo.com/golf/pga/players/Marc+Leishman/8442/scorecard/2014/35','Marc Leishman','64') 
WHERE 'name/_text' = 'Marc Leishman'
```

Answer (score 1):

**Q:** Is there anyway to use an UPDATE statement similar to this form:

```
UPDATE mytable 
   SET (col1, col2)
VALUES ('val1', 'val2')
 WHERE somecol = 'someval'
```

**A:** No, there is no similar syntax for an `UPDATE` statement.

The syntax of the `UPDATE` statement is very specific. There's no need to repeat the documentation here. Ref: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html

---

It's not clear what you are trying to achieve. So I hesitate to recommend `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`, though this is a useful pattern for "refreshing" a table from a source file (if there's a UNIQUE KEY in the table, and a value for the UNIQUE KEY provided in the source.)

I also hesitate to recommend loading a temporary table using `INSERT`, and then subsequently running a multi-table `UPDATE` statement to update the target table from the temporary table.

Comment: This is the only sensible answer.

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible.

Other solutions: Create your Query String with PHP, and Use an Array of Cell Name and Content to Update or Insert. Build the Query String automatically.

Or Use "on duplicate key" to combine Insert or Update

```
insert into 
import_io (total, thru) 
VALUES('$total', '$thru') 
on duplicate key 
    update set total='$total
    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the array using `SELECT` modify it and the use `UPDATE` to update the column.

Since I don't know the programming language that you are using I can not give you an example.

Answer (score 0):

To insert:

> INSERT INTO Table_name (the_names_of_variebles) VALUES
>   (In_Values_in_the_same_pattern)

To import:

> SELECT * FROM Table_name WHERE variable_name = 'input_to_find'